# How to force xlim unchanged permanently, even after plt.cla() in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to force the xlim unchanged permanently, even after `plt.cla()` in matplotlib with Jupyter Notebook.

```
data=[[0,1],[0,1]]
plt.ylim(0,4)
plt.plot(*data)
plt.cla()

data=[[0,2],[0,2]]
plt.plot(*data) # <- rescaled automatically...
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.cla()` clears the axes and all the information about limits stored in it. 
Options you have:

- Store the previous values and reset them to the new axes.

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  data=[[0,1],[0,1]]
  plt.ylim(0,4)
  plt.plot(*data)
  xlims = plt.xlim()
  plt.cla()

  data=[[0,2],[0,2]]
  plt.plot(*data)
  plt.xlim(xlims)

  plt.show()
  ```
- Don't clear the axes. Instead maybe just remove the content from the axes.

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  data=[[0,1],[0,1]]
  plt.ylim(0,4)
  plt.plot(*data)

  for line in plt.gca().lines:
      line.remove()

  data=[[0,2],[0,2]]
  plt.plot(*data)

  plt.show()
  ```